# Clicking on each div from a container in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to automate the access to https://www.nemlig.com/ 's pages and I don't know how to iterate through (let's say) 8 `div`, all contained in another `div`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\lib\chromedriver_77.0.3865.40.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nemlig.com/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".timeslot-prompt.initial-animation-done")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel'][class^='pro']"))).send_keys('2300')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.prompt__button"))).click()
```

Above is the code so far. After completing this, I want to access the date buttons one by one at a given time interval.

[image]

I have issues achieving this as all of them look the same in HTML. How can I tell the webdriver to click the next div inside the container until the condition that all of the 8 dates have been accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located`() and following CSS selector. I have added a date checks to check that if date in not available in the list then click on that date.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\user\lib\chromedriver_77.0.3865.40.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.nemlig.com/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".timeslot-prompt.initial-animation-done")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel'][class^='pro']"))).send_keys('2300')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.prompt__button"))).click()
dates=[]
elements=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-automation='dayDateTmSlt']")))
for ele in elements:
    if ele.text not in dates:
       dates.append(ele.text)
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)
       time.sleep(3)
```